# Can you enable both Object Lock AND a Lifecycle policy on the same S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a versioned bucket that I would like to enable Object Lock on. In addition, I also want to create a Lifecycle policy that will transition files older than some age to a different S3 Storage Class -- specifically, from Standard to Standard-IA.

Is there any conflict between these two properties? As I understand it, enabling Object Lock on a versioned bucket will not allow you to delete any versions of any files in the bucket. But since modifying the storage class of a file isn't a deletion, there's no reason why I couldn't enable both, right? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it's surprisingly hard to find a clear answer online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Object Lock is 'enabled' at the bucket level, it is 'activated' at the object level. So, there is no prohibition from enabling Object Lock *and* using a Lifecycle policy.

Enabling Object Lock on a bucket requires **Versioning** to be activated on the bucket.

From [AWS Announces Amazon S3 Object Lock in all AWS Regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-object-lock/):

> S3 Object Lock protection is maintained regardless of which storage class the object resides in and throughout S3 Lifecycle transitions between storage classes.

Answer (score 2):

While your lifecycle policy doesn't try to permanently delete an object version during the locked retention period, there is no incompatibility between "Locked" and "Lifecycle" S3 features

From [Managing Object Lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock-managing.html#object-lock-managing-lifecycle):

> Object lifecycle management configurations continue to function normally on protected objects, including placing delete markers. However, protected object versions remain safe from being deleted or overwritten by a lifecycle configuration